# Swift3 version for emojilessStringWithSubstitution

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

My current implementation has :

```
var emojilessStringWithSubstitution: String {
    let emojiPatterns = [UnicodeScalar(0x10000)...UnicodeScalar(0x10FFFF), UnicodeScalar(0x2600)...UnicodeScalar(0x27ff)]
    return self.unicodeScalars
        .filter { ucScalar in !(emojiPatterns.contains{ $0 ~= ucScalar }) }
        .reduce("") { $0 + String($1) }
}
```

errors that occur are : 
1. Integer literals overflow when stored into UInt8
2. when i store the unicode scalar in variables and then try to assign then the error is Binary operator '...' cannot be applied to two 'UnicodeScalar?' operands

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as below,

```
    var emojilessStringWithSubstitution: String {
    let emojiPatterns = [0x10000...0x10FFFF, 0x2600...0x27ff]
    return self.unicodeScalars
        .filter { ucScalar in !(emojiPatterns.contains{ $0 ~= Int(ucScalar.value) }) }
        .reduce("") { $0 + String($1) }
}
```